# WPF/Silverlight layout best practice

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

What would the best practice be for laying out the following item?

[Valid XHTML http://www.hughgrice.com/layout.gif](http://www.hughgrice.com/layout.gif).

I am particularly interested in what controls I should use and how I position the delete icon to appear on the right-hand side and the tools icon to appear in the middle always?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that mixed WPF Silverlight questions are often a bad idea.  There is clearly a correct answer here if you are using WPF, DockPanel.  OTH the answer isn't so clear cut when using Silverlight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preferred panel for this case is the DockPanel rather than a Grid:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button>Add</Button>
    <Label>This is a label</Label>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">Del</Button>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center">Setting</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: DockPanel doesn't exist out of the box in Silverlight, its available in the toolkit though.  If you had other reasons to include toolkit controls I would agree DockPanel describes the intent much better.

Comment: You're right for Silverlight, but as I can't live without the DockPanel I extracted it from the toolkit. This way I avoid loading the toolkit entirely.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="Plusbutton" />
    <Label Text="This is a Label" Margin="3,0,3,0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Image Source="Gear" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Image Source="Minusbutton" Margin ="3,0,3,0" Grid.Column="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Good but I would suggest adding the Grid.Column="0" for clarity.

Comment: Why always use a Grid for layout? It is too verbose for no benefit compared to a DockPanel.

Comment: In Silverlight anyway, Grid doesn't require a hideous XAML namespace prefix like: <Toolkit:DockPanel ...>, <Image Toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left" ...> etc. When it finally becomes part of the main control set hopefully this ugliness will go away.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `t:` as a namespace prefix instead of `Toolkit:`.

Comment: @Mart In this case, you could get away with a DockPanel, but often Grid lets you compose things that you would have to nest DockPanels and StackPanels repeatedly that Grid can do easier.

Comment: I certainly use both Grid and DockPanel, but I statically use more DockPanel. When it clearly is a "grid" I use it, otherwise there are underused panels like UniformGrid. Again you have less choice with Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

The `Grid` is good for this:-

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0">
     <!-- Your content here -->
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1">
     <!-- Your content here -->
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2">
     <!-- Your content here -->
   </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

This approach decouples the basic Grid of Left, Center and Right content from the content itself.  In your example the Left StackPanel will have two items in it.  The content of each panel need only be concerned about its layout relative to other sibling items in the panel.

Comment: Good but I would suggest adding the Grid.Column="0" for clarity.

Comment: @Josh: Added to ease your sense of aesthetics. ;)

Comment: LOL I know I am such a pain in the ass when it comes to XAML.